# With React Native, how can I render the second component in my Tab navigation before it is in view?

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

The second component is very simple and I was wondering if I can render it prior so that there is no load time. Thank you!

Comment: Could You post some code or even a small example of what you are trying to acheive

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Comment: Sorry, here's my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TabNavigatorConfig` lazy prop.

Pass `lazy={false}` so that your views may load at initial start, then you will have not any load time!

check this:

```
const regStack = TabNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Register: { screen: Register }
  },

  {
    initialRouteName: "Login",
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",

    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#F0FFFF",
    },

    animationEnabled: true,
    swipeEnabled: true,
    lazy: false 
  }
);
```